# Is there a way to use the parent selector (&) with selector-append (sass:selector)

Tags: sass

I am trying to achieve the following in scss:

```
&.-icon-default, &.-icon-darker, &.-icon-dark {...}
```

However, using selector-append like:

```
#{selector-append(".-icon", "-default, -darker, -dark")} {...}
```

helps me achieve the following:

```
.-icon-default, .-icon-darker, .-icon-dark {...}
```

So I want to use the parent selector along with selector-append. Passing it directly to the strings in argument of selector-append gives me an error. Is there a way to solve this using selector-append or will I have to hardcode all such instances without using the selector-append function?

Comment: I've tried doing the following: 
$selector: selector-append(&, ".-icon")
#{selector-append($selector, "-default", "darker", "dark")} {...} 

But that doesn't work either.

Comment: Maybe it is just unclear for me, but what exact CSS3 output do you want to achieve? Would you mind elaborating a bit further?

Answer (score 1):

Include the `&` in the first argument. This SCSS:

```scss
div {
    #{selector-append("&.-icon", "-default, -darker, -dark")} {
        font-size: 2rem;
    }
}
```

... compiles to this CSS:

```css
div.-icon-default, div.-icon-darker, div.-icon-dark {
  font-size: 2rem;
}
```

Is that the result you want?